# SQL Server Deadlock, single query, page lock. Including deadlock graph, and table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization, deadlock

We experience deadlocks in a multi user environment. It happens in about 1% of the times.

It is of type page lock and happens only at a single query. Something I haven't seen before.

Since this happens only in a production environment which we cannot reproduce I would like to ask for a little help/thoughts on how to fix this.

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [ext].[PickingRows](
    [PickingRowId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OrderId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [RecId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [RouteId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ReferenceType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TransferReference] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PalletTypeHeaderId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ItemNo] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Weight] [decimal](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [SSCC] [nvarchar](18) NULL,
    [BatchNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BestBeforeDate] [nvarchar](6) NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DataAreaId] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConsafeId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedByUser] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [CreatedByApplication] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [CreatedByHost] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [UpdatedByUser] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [UpdatedByApplication] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [UpdatedByHost] [varchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PickingRows] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PickingRowId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Deadlock graph:**

```
<deadlock>
  <victim-list>
    <victimProcess id="process8054bdc8" />
  </victim-list>
  <process-list>
    <process id="process8054bdc8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 13:1:1435527" waittime="2253" ownerId="26857711" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.657" XDES="0x116e4d890" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="1980" status="suspended" spid="58" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.550" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.550" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXXX" hostpid="1292" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="26857711" currentdb="13" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="266" sqlhandle="0x02000000224c023b6d575eec65b98a1620bc85b551bd7a20" />
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="476" stmtend="978" sqlhandle="0x02000000776ebd001430def4543cc4d0740b5e0b643fb45e" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
    <process id="process8054abc8" taskpriority="0" logused="256" waitresource="PAGE: 13:1:1435527" waittime="2205" ownerId="26857710" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.637" XDES="0x116e4d620" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="4872" status="suspended" spid="71" sbid="0" ecid="2" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.217" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.217" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXXX" hostpid="1292" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="26857710" currentdb="13" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="266" sqlhandle="0x02000000224c023b6d575eec65b98a1620bc85b551bd7a20" />
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="476" stmtend="978" sqlhandle="0x020000006380f42992ac44812fc42ce93a32f85b8b2fd3e8" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf />
    </process>
    <process id="process3f39948" taskpriority="0" logused="10000" waittime="2042" schedulerid="2" kpid="740" status="suspended" spid="71" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.217" lastbatchcompleted="2015-02-03T10:25:34.217" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="XXX" hostpid="1292" loginname="XXX" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="26857710" currentdb="13" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
      <executionStack>
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="266" sqlhandle="0x02000000224c023b6d575eec65b98a1620bc85b551bd7a20" />
        <frame procname="" line="13" stmtstart="476" stmtend="978" sqlhandle="0x020000006380f42992ac44812fc42ce93a32f85b8b2fd3e8" />
      </executionStack>
      <inputbuf>
if(exists (
 select * 
 from ext.PickingRows
 where DataAreaId = 'KSE1'
  and RouteId = '334417'
  and ItemNo = '8277'
  and BatchNo = '150130038'
  and SSCC is null
  and RecId = 5638470269 
  and UserName = '8084'
))
begin
 update ext.PickingRows
 set Qty = Qty + 1,
  Weight = Weight + 1 * 1.87
 where DataAreaId = 'KSE1'
  and RouteId = '334417'
  and ItemNo = '8277'
  and BatchNo = '150130038'
  and SSCC is null
  and RecId = 5638470269
  and UserName = '8084'
end
else
begin
insert into ext.PickingRows (DataAreaId,
RouteId, 
RecId, 
OrderId, 
ReferenceType, 
ItemNo, 
Qty, 
[Weight], 
BatchNo, 
UserName, 
[Status], 
BestBeforeDate)
values
('KSE1',
'334417',
5638470269,
'63309',
2,  
'8277', 
1, 
1 * 1.87, 
'150130038', 
'8084', 
'7200', 
'150209')
end

   </inputbuf>
    </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1435527" dbid="13" objectname="" id="lockbd444500" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594040025088">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process3f39948" mode="U" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8054bdc8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="1435527" dbid="13" objectname="" id="lockbd444500" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594040025088">
      <owner-list />
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process8054abc8" mode="U" requestType="wait" />
      </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <exchangeEvent id="Pipe1736c0500" WaitType="e_waitPipeGetRow" nodeId="3">
      <owner-list>
        <owner id="process8054abc8" />
      </owner-list>
      <waiter-list>
        <waiter id="process3f39948" />
      </waiter-list>
    </exchangeEvent>
  </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

The table itself has about 350 rows without any triggers, foreign keys or special indexes.

What I thought of doing is optimizing the query as follows:

```
UPDATE ext.PickingRows
SET 
  Qty = Qty + 1,
  Weight = Weight + 1 * 1.87
WHERE
  DataAreaId = 'KSE1'
  and RouteId = '334417'
  and ItemNo = '8277'
  and BatchNo = '150130038'
  and SSCC is null
  and RecId = 5638470269
  and UserName = '8084'

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ext.PickingRows (DataAreaId, RouteId, RecId,  OrderId, ReferenceType, ItemNo, Qty, [Weight], BatchNo, UserName, [Status], BestBeforeDate)
    VALUES ('KSE1', '334417', 5638470269, '63309', 2, '8277', 1, 1 * 1.87, '150130038', '8084', '7200', '150209')
END
```

This way I skip the unneeded SELECT statement.

My question is if this could solve the deadlock problem or if any of you have any thoughts about that.

Problem is that updating these queries require a production stop (for about 1 minute) at the customer which is running 24/7 which is not ideal to do this many times....

Huge thanks!

Edit:
Maybe it is good to say that it is running without any transactions and isolation levels are not changed so it is set to TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

Comment: Maybe you can find some relevant information in this article: http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx

Comment: That is one of the articles I read. In the last paragraph I just don't really understand why serializable isolation level is needed...

Comment: How many rows does the SQL Server think would updated by the query? And how parallel does it want to run? Seeing as the owner process has  U lock and the waiter also wants a U lock it could indicate multiple updates trying to run

Answer (score 0):

The most common situation a deadlock I've come across is with a select statement followed by a update.

The thing that happens is that two querys at the same time takes readlocks, then both querys need to update the locks to exclusive locks, so they have to wait on each other (deadlock occurs).

To solve this I think your solution could work with an update instead of the select statement, another way is to try the UPDLOCK table hint on the select statement.

```
if(exists 
(select *  from ext.PickingRows (UPDLOCK)
....
...
```

More on table hints: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx